# jQuery selector caching issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, caching, jquery-selectors

The problem is, when I wrote every time HTML tags' ids the code below works. But when I cache them, it doesn't. What am I missing?

Here is my code:

```
var NewFormContainer=$("#NewUserFormContainer"), opener=$("#nufcOpen"), closer=$("#nufcClose"), NewForm=$("#NewUserForm");
$(function() {
    $( "#userType" ).buttonset();
    $(".btn").button();

    closer.button({
        icons: {
            primary: "ui-icon-closethick"
        }, text: false
    }).click(function(){
        NewFormContainer.slideUp("slow");
    });
    opener.click(function(){
        NewFormContainer.slideDown("slow");
    });
});
```

BTW, no error in console. And I'm using jQ-UI too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you cache them, they're being evaludated before document.ready.  Try this:

```
var NewFormContainer="#NewUserFormContainer", opener="#nufcOpen", closer="#nufcClose", NewForm="#NewUserForm";
$(function() {
  opener = $(opener);
  closer = $(closer);
  NewFormContainer = $(NewFormContainer);
  NewForm = $(NewForm);
  ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to `cache` them when the `dom` is ready.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#userType" ).buttonset();
    $(".btn").button();

    var NewFormContainer=$("#NewUserFormContainer"),
        opener=$("#nufcOpen"),
        closer=$("#nufcClose"),
        NewForm=$("#NewUserForm");

    closer.button({
      icons: {
        primary: "ui-icon-closethick"
      }, text: false
    }).click(function(){
        NewFormContainer.slideUp("slow");
    });

    opener.click(function(){
        NewFormContainer.slideDown("slow");
    });
});
```